# UML inside visual studio source code files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uml

I'm working with C# applications.
I know it's possible to create UML drawings and view them inside Visual Studio.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create UML-like diagrams inside `*.cs` files (something like a `///<some_tag>` which might be converted to UML-diagram drawings).

Comment: You want ASCII-Art?

Comment: No, I'm looking for something which translates ASCII into tooltip-like drawings (if that exists in Visual Studio).

Comment: I don't think there is something like that. Where would you put such a comment? I mean those documentation comments are for classes, methods etc. parts of a software architecture. But most of the different UML Diagram types show architecture stuff that aren't easily broken down on that level. Maybe a good example helps what you want to document with a visual diagram to come up with ideas.

Comment: We _are_ talking about class diagrams, are we? Could as well be State or Sequence or Entity Relationship Diagrams?